# Checking if a statement is true for three consecutive years in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create some code to determine if a certain statement is true for three consecutive years. This statement is, for example, that the amount needs to be negative for three consecutive years. Only if that is true, the third row should be marked in a new column with a 1, otherwise, the rows should be marked as a 0.

To further elaborate on what I try to do, I've created the following dataset:

| ID | Year | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2022 | 2 |
| 001 | 2021 | -9 |
| 001 | 2020 | -10 |
| 001 | 2019 | -16 |
| 001 | 2018 | -20 |
| 002 | 2022 | 400 |
| 002 | 2021 | 300 |
| 002 | 2020 | -200 |
| 002 | 2019 | -600 |
| 002 | 2018 | -500 |

And the outcome should look somewhat like this:

| ID | Year | Amount | Y/N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2022 | 2 | 0 |
| 001 | 2021 | -9 | 1 |
| 001 | 2020 | -10 | 1 |
| 001 | 2019 | -16 | 0 |
| 001 | 2018 | -20 | 0 |
| 002 | 2022 | 400 | 0 |
| 002 | 2021 | 300 | 0 |
| 002 | 2020 | -200 | 1 |
| 002 | 2019 | -600 | 0 |
| 002 | 2018 | -500 | 0 |

Does anybody know how I could code this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it :

```r
df <- read.table(h=T, text="ID  Year    Amount
001 2022    2
001 2021    -9
001 2020    -10
001 2019    -16
001 2018    -20
002 2022    400
002 2021    300
002 2020    -200
002 2019    -600
002 2018    -500")

library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(YN = rev(diff(c(0,0,0, cumsum(rev(Amount)<0)), 3)  == 3)) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#>       ID  Year Amount YN   
#>    <int> <int>  <int> <lgl>
#>  1     1  2022      2 FALSE
#>  2     1  2021     -9 TRUE 
#>  3     1  2020    -10 TRUE 
#>  4     1  2019    -16 FALSE
#>  5     1  2018    -20 FALSE
#>  6     2  2022    400 FALSE
#>  7     2  2021    300 FALSE
#>  8     2  2020   -200 TRUE 
#>  9     2  2019   -600 FALSE
#> 10     2  2018   -500 FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

In base R:

```
df$YN <- ave(df$Amount, df$ID, FUN = function(x) rev(diff(c(0,0,0, cumsum(rev(x)<0)), 3)  == 3)) == 1
```

Here's a walkthrough :

```
df %>% 
  arrange(ID, Year) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(
    cond = Amount < 0,
    cumsum = cumsum(cond),
    diff = diff(c(0,0,0, cumsum), 3),
    YN = diff == 3) # %>% arrange(ID, desc(Year)) # to put back in original shape
#> # A tibble: 10 × 7
#> # Groups:   ID [2]
#>       ID  Year Amount cond  cumsum  diff YN   
#>    <int> <int>  <int> <lgl>  <int> <dbl> <lgl>
#>  1     1  2018    -20 TRUE       1     1 FALSE
#>  2     1  2019    -16 TRUE       2     2 FALSE
#>  3     1  2020    -10 TRUE       3     3 TRUE 
#>  4     1  2021     -9 TRUE       4     3 TRUE 
#>  5     1  2022      2 FALSE      4     2 FALSE
#>  6     2  2018   -500 TRUE       1     1 FALSE
#>  7     2  2019   -600 TRUE       2     2 FALSE
#>  8     2  2020   -200 TRUE       3     3 TRUE 
#>  9     2  2021    300 FALSE      3     2 FALSE
#> 10     2  2022    400 FALSE      3     1 FALSE
```

And an easier solution to read, not generalisable to big spans:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(YN = (Amount < 0) + lead(Amount < 0, default = 0) + lead(Amount < 0, 2, default = 0) == 3) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Yeah it's not super pretty, but using diff for consecutive values is an idiom, it was to be used in the first days of the advent of code last year if I'm not mistaken. Using 2 times `rev` is a useful trick too with `cumsum()`

Answer (score 0):

Using the dataset

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(rep(1,5,),rep(2,5)), year = rep(seq(2022,2018),2), amount = c(2,-9,-10,-16,-20,400,300,-200,-600,-500))
```

A `sapply` function can be used:

```
df$test <- ifelse(sapply(seq(1,nrow(df)), function(x) all(subset(df, df$id == df$id[x] & df$year %in% seq(df$year[x]-2,df$year[x]))$amount < 0) & nrow(subset(df, df$id == df$id[x] & df$year %in% seq(df$year[x]-2,df$year[x]))) > 2),1,0)
```

That gives:

```
df
       id year amount test
    1   1 2022      2    0
    2   1 2021     -9    1
    3   1 2020    -10    1
    4   1 2019    -16    0
    5   1 2018    -20    0
    6   2 2022    400    0
    7   2 2021    300    0
    8   2 2020   -200    1
    9   2 2019   -600    0
    10  2 2018   -500    0
```

Breakdown:

`ifelse` to change the TRUE/FALSE from the SAPPLY to 1/0

`sapply` to iterate per row

`all` to test whether the condition holds for all values inside the subset

`subset` to select the last three years and the correct id

`$amount < 0` to test the condition

Answer (score 0):

You could use data.table package.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[order(Year), YN := match(Reduce(`+`, shift(Amount<0, 0:2)), 3, 0), ID]

#        ID  Year Amount    YN
#  1:     1  2022      2     0
#  2:     1  2021     -9     1
#  3:     1  2020    -10     1
#  4:     1  2019    -16     0
#  5:     1  2018    -20     0
#  6:     2  2022    400     0
#  7:     2  2021    300     0
#  8:     2  2020   -200     1
#  9:     2  2019   -600     0
# 10:     2  2018   -500     0
```

#### data

```
df = structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
                    Year = c(2022, 2021, 2020, 2019, 2018, 2022, 2021, 2020, 2019, 2018), 
                    Amount = c(2, -9, -10, -16, -20, 400, 300, -200, -600, -500)), 
               row.names = c(NA, -10L), 
               class = "data.frame")
```